# if statement based on a command

Tags: exit-status

I found this way to do `if` commands:

```
$if echo test | grep st ; then echo yes ; fi ; echo $?
test
yes
0
```

Looks good. Let's try a non-match:

```
$if echo test | grep 123 ; then echo yes ; fi ; echo $?
0
```

That's not right. The `if` statement functions properly, but it returns a zero exit code.

Can someone explain this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$?` after an `if` block contains the exit status of the `if` statement. The standard [specifies that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07)

> The exit status of the `if` command shall be the exit status of the `then` or `else` *compound-list* that was executed, or zero, if none was executed.

In the first case you’re seeing the exit status of the `echo yes` command. In the second case, no command is executed in a `then` or `else` block, so the exit status is 0.

Answer (score 1):

From bash manual (formatting and emphasis added):

> *if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi*
>
> The if list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the then list is executed.  Otherwise, each elif list is executed in turn, and if its exit sta‐
>                 tus  is  zero, the corresponding then list is executed and the command completes.  Otherwise, the else list is executed, if present.  The exit status
>                 is the exit status of the last command executed, **or zero if no condition tested true.**

So the important part is to be aware the exit status of *what* you're actually looking at. In your example, `echo test | grep 123` the last command didn't exit successfully. If you did `grep` first and then tested exit status you'd see it returns non-zero exit status:

```
$ grep 'noexist' /etc/passwd
$ echo $?
1
```

By contrast, within if statement the command as condition didn't test true, therefore in accordance with specifications and manual - exit status is 0.

On side note, please do `grep '123'` , because unquoted pattern can be whole other bag of problems if there is a file 123 in your current directory.

---

**Side note on grep and quoting patterns**

Stephen Kitt requested in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400868/if-statement-based-on-a-command/400871?noredirect=1#comment716090_400871) elaboration on the last paragraph. This is not necessarily related to the topic of this question and this has been touched upon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21492833/3701431), and I answered something similar [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/894149/295286), but I'll go on a tangent because this is fun. Let's look at two examples.

Here, we have `grep input`, simple unquoted string. `grep`'s syntax is such that it will consider first string as pattern. No problem here, this works:

```
bash-4.3$ strace -e trace=execve grep input <<< "this is input line"
execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "input"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
this is input line
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

However, look what happens when you have (what you think is) regular expression.

```
bash-4.3$ strace -e trace=execve grep input* <<< "this is input line"
execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "input.txt", "input.txt.bak"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

The shell saw your `*` and performed pathname expansion. And now actual real command that shell runs is `grep some_file_1 some_file_2 some_file_3`, and in accordance with `grep` syntax - `grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]` - the command will now look for string `input.txt` inside `input.txt.bak`. In fact, look at this:

```
bash-4.3$ echo "I have input.txt here" > input.txt.bak
bash-4.3$ grep input* <<< "this is input line"
I have input.txt here
```

The input string is completely ignored, `grep` only searches the expanded filenames , and you've got result that you didn't intend to have.